# Why is my object moving in the wrong direction?

Tags: java, collision

When two of my objects collide, I want one of them to push the other.

```
while (checkCollision(this, cl)){ 
//cl is referring to the other entity, non-cl things my entity
                        double an = Assist.angle(new Vector3f(cl.z, 0, cl.x),
                                                 new Vector3f(z, 0, x)); 
                        double moveZ = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(an));
                        double moveX = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(an));
                        cl.z += moveZ;
                        cl.x += moveX;
                    }
```

The `checkCollision()` method works perfectly fine, detecting if my two objects (in this case 3D ships) have collided.

I am then getting the angle between the other object and my current one, and then using that angle, I am pushing away the other object. However - It isn't working.

The other object always seems to be pushed torwards the +x direction, and the Z doesn't seem to have any strict pattern, but isn't working correctly either.

Here is my method to calculate the angle (`Assist.angle()`):

```
public static double angle(Vector3f vec1, Vector3f vec2){
    double so = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(((vec1.z) - vec2.z), ((vec1.x) - vec2.x)));
    return Math.abs(so);
}
```

There must obviously be something blatantly wrong here - But I'm not seeing it, and I've been working for hours to try and get this code to work.

Comment: A few questions: Why z instead of y? What angle is angle supposed to calculate? a heading? angle on the bow?

Comment: @CandiedOrange Because Y is pointing upwards. I don't care about upwards. The angle is supposed to calculate the angle that object2 would have to face to look at object1.

Comment: Upwards as in north or upwards as in up?

Comment: @CandiedOrange It's not really relevant now, but I am making a 3D game. In 3D, X is always north/south, Y is always up/down, Z is always left/right. http://i.gyazo.com/7d138199130fa4b9264de8f77b67677c.png

Comment: Right but I'm on StackOverflow so I don't trust people to be following conventions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.atan2()` takes vector cords not angles, radian or otherwise.  What it returns is in radians.

For historical reasons to stupid to go into `Math.atan2()` expects `y` before `x`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double,%20double)

Also I don't think that `Math.abs(so)` at the end is helping anything.

Take a look at this:

[image]

From your comments it sounds like you think you need Ab.  You don't.  If you just want to bounce off (which is a grand simplification) you need Ta and it's compliment.

Comment: I thought I was putting vector coordinates in it? And I'm definitely converting it into degrees after use. I've reversed my Z and X functions on `Math.atan2()`, however it has not appeared to solve the issue.

Comment: @Joehot200 Please explain why vector coordinates would ever need conversion from degrees to radians when such conversions are for angles.

Comment: I've posted the new code in the overview. The result is exactly the same.

Comment: I'm incredibly, incredibly, confused right now. However, it does appear to be working. Even though the same code earlier wasn't? I'm very confused. Anyway, I'll come back to you if I have any more issues - And thank you for the help and useful information!

Comment: Oh, I somewhat understand the issue now. Despite what you said having fixed it, I had a freezing issue which froze the game which made it appear to not work, and then when the game unfroze my ship was on the OTHER SIDE of the other ship (had gone though it), causing the other ship to appear to be move the wrong way.